# Transparent menu bar when displaying list of questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

Sometimes, when having a list of questions open, the menu bar (quesions, tags, answer,...) appears transparently.
I still could not reproduce it nor find out what causes this, but it appears when having the app open for some time...

[image: example image]

I will update this post as soon as I have found out more.
Up to now, this behaviour occurred after opening a certain post, editing or commenting it, adding an answer, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixed in 1.4.3.7, shipping towards the end of January.

I only reproduced it once, but the background view somehow got its height stuck at zero.  We were supposed to be avoiding this by suppressing layouts when the height of the view was zero but now we'll be explicitly resizing the background to the size of the view when laid out.